# Issue with Accessing Twitter API using Tweepy with Free Level Access

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

I've implemented a Python script using `tweepy` to fetch the most recent tweets of a user and save them to an Excel file. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

# My Twitter API credentials
API_KEY = 'x'
API_SECRET_KEY = 'x'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xx'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxx'

# Authentication with tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def get_tweets(username, count=200):
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=count, tweet_mode="extended")
    tweet_data = [{
        'tweet_id': tweet.id,
        'created_at': tweet.created_at,
        'text': tweet.full_text,
        'likes': tweet.favorite_count,
        'retweets': tweet.retweet_count
    } for tweet in tweets]
    return tweet_data

def main():
    user = 'x'
    data = get_tweets(user, count=200)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel('twitter_data.xlsx', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I encounter the following error when running the script:

```
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product
```

It's worth noting that I'm currently on the Free Level Access of the Twitter API.

Do I need to upgrade my access to use this endpoint or is there another solution to access the data using the Free Level Access?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the **Twitter API v1.1**, which no longer supports the **Search Recent Tweets** feature.

You have to utilize the **Twitter API v2** to use the same feature, but it requires **Basic Level Access**.

Example:

```py
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)

# Search Tweets
query = "Twitter"
max_tweets = 100
searched_tweets = tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=query, max_results=max_tweets).flatten(limit=max_tweets)
```

If you are planning to retrieve **a maximum of 100 tweets at a time**, then you don't need **Pagination**.

So, you can use the following line of code:

```py
searched_tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=max_tweets)
```

For more information:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/v2_pagination.html

I hope this helps.